# Hosting a wcf in local IIS using ssl

Tags: c#, wcf, ssl, https, iis-8

I am learning WCF and i need to create a simple WCF service with a https binding. Need to have it as secure as possible.

So far i succeeded in creating a self-hosting wcf by using this guide:

[Codeproject enable certificates on WCF](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36683/simple-steps-to-enable-X-certificates-on-WCF)

Managed to consume it, everything looks great. But the real problems appear when i try to host this in IIS 8. Local IIS, not IIS express.

I created a new wcf application in visual studio 2012, and in project's properties -> Web -> servers, i selected Local IIS, project URL: `https://localhost/AdminService` , Create virtual directory.

This added an application under Default Web Site in IIS Manager. The thing is, using the same web-config as my self-hosted app, roughly modified, did not work.
After altering it a bit, i got to this:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="wsHttpEndpointBinding">
      <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
        <message clientCredentialType="Certificate"/>
        <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>

<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="WCFServiceCertificate.SecureServiceBehavior"
    name="AdminService.AdminService">
    <!--<host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="https://localhost:1234/AdminService" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>-->
    <endpoint address="https://localhost/AdminService" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsHttpEndpointBinding"
      contract="AdminServiceContract.IAdminService">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
    <!--<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />-->
  </service>
</services>

<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="WCFServiceCertificate.SecureServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
      <serviceCredentials>
        <clientCertificate>
          <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerTrust" />
        </clientCertificate>
        <serviceCertificate findValue="CertAdminService" storeLocation="LocalMachine"
          storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
      </serviceCredentials>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<protocolMapping>
    <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
</protocolMapping>    
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

That CertAdminService certificate was not created with makecert, like i did in the self-hosted wcf, but i created it with iis manager's "create self-signed certificate".
Then, on Default Web Site -> bindings, i added a new binding, https, and selected this certificate.

The problem is, even if i choose browse (*:443) on default web site, or my application, i get the following error:
Unable to make a secure connection to the server. This may be a problem with the server, or it may be requiring a client authentication certificate that you don't have.
Error code: ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

I have no idea what am i doing wrong. Also, having the mexHttpsBinding enabled, if i try to add service reference to another project, i can discover the service, but i get the following error:

"There was an error downloading '`https://localhost/AdminService/AdminService.svc/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/$metadata`'.
The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
The handshake failed due to an unexpected packet format.
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: '`https://localhost/AdminService/AdminService.svc`'.
An error occurred while making the HTTP request to `https://localhost/AdminService/AdminService.svc`.

This could be due to the fact that the server certificate is not configured properly with HTTP.SYS in the HTTPS case. This could also be caused by a mismatch of the security binding between the client and the server.
The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
The handshake failed due to an unexpected packet format.
If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again."

Any help will be much appreciated, i kind of ran out of ideas. According to other posts on stackoverflow that i've read, this should've work. Maybe i'm doing something wrong and i don't know what.

Thank you, and sorry for the long post.

Edit:

Here is the consuming client's web.config:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <wsHttpBinding>
                <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IAdminService">
                    <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
                        <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
                        <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </wsHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="https://localhost/AdminService"
                binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IAdminService"
                contract="AdminServiceContract.IAdminService" name="WSHttpBinding_IAdminService" behaviorConfiguration="CustomBehavior">
                <identity>
                    <dns value="WCfServer" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
        </client>
      <behaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
          <behavior name="CustomBehavior">
            <clientCredentials>
              <clientCertificate findValue="CertAdminService" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName"
                storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" />
              <serviceCertificate>
                <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerTrust"/>
              </serviceCertificate>
            </clientCredentials>
          </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
      </behaviors>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```